# using C# and UI Automation to grab contents of custom control-type

Tags: c#, .net, automation, custom-controls

In the image below: The top element is `Table` type but using Inspect to check, the `IsTablePatternAvailable` is `False`, so I can't control it as a Table.
The next level is made up of "Custom" type -- "Data Panel" and "Header Panel". All the types are marked on the image.

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QojMW.png)

I need to be able:

1. to select Rows in this area
2. to grab a Value from each cell

The table `IsTablePatternAvailable` is `False` and the elements below it are all "Custom" type so I can't access the grid using the normal 'Table' or 'Grid' pattern.The problem is since that's not a common type element - I have no idea how to google this problem or solve it myself.

I've already tried to threat this Area as as a grid, as a combobox, but nothing solved my problem so far. Does anybody have any advice how to grab data from this area and iterate through rows?
Thank you very much!